# Write pandas table to impala

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs, impala

Using the impyla module, I've downloaded the results of an impala query into a pandas dataframe, done analysis, and would now like to write the results back to a table on impala, or at least to an hdfs file.

However, I cannot find any information on how to do this, or even how to ssh into the impala shell and write the table from there.

What I'd like to do:

```
from impala.dbapi import connect
from impala.util import as_pandas

# connect to my host and port
conn=connect(host='myhost', port=111) 

# create query to save table as pandas df
create_query = """
     SELECT * FROM {}
     """.format(my_table_name)

# run query on impala
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(create_query)

# store results as pandas data frame
pandas_df = as_pandas(cur)
cur.close()
```

Once I've done whatever I need to do with pandas_df, save those results back to impala as a table.

```
# create query to save new_df back to impala
save_query = """
    CREATE TABLE new_table AS
        SELECT * 
        FROM pandas_df
    """

# run query on impala
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(save_query)
cur.close()
```

The above scenario would be ideal, but I'd be happy if I could figure out how to ssh into impala-shell and do this from python, or even just save the table to hdfs. I'm writing this as a script for other users, so it's essential to have this all done within the script. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're going to love [Ibis](https://github.com/cloudera/ibis/)! It has the HDFS functions (`put`, namely) and wraps the Impala DML and DDL you'll need to make this easy.

The general approach I've used for something similar is to save your pandas table to a CSV, `HDFS.put` that on to the cluster, and then create a new table using that CSV as the data source.

You don't *need* Ibis for this, but it should make it a little bit easier and may be a nice tool for you if you're already familiar with pandas (Ibis was also created by Wes, who wrote pandas).

Comment: I was actually just reading up on Ibis the other day. Sounds like I'll have to check it out.

Comment: Hi im getting an error in Ibis in the db.create_table('mytablename',mydataframe).
The error is  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0). 
Any idea what could be? @Isaac

Answer (score 3):

I am trying to do same thing and I figured out a way to do this with an example provided with `impyla`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(range(16), (4, 4)), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
df.to_sql(name=”test_df”, con=conn, flavor=”mysql”)
```

This works fine and table in impala (backend mysql) works fine.

However, I got stuck on getting text values in as impala tries to do analysis on columns and I get cast errors. (It would be really nice if possible to implicitly cast from string to [var]char(N) in impyla.)